# How to create mutiple instances of the same field in a react form

Tags: reactjs, formik

Hi I want to create a form set like this:

[image]

If I click Add One, it adds one. If I press x, it deletes one.

How can I produce this in formik?
Is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: Please try something and ask if you're stuck somewhere.

Comment: whatever code runs to add one, let it take a parameter of how many times, and loop that many times to add "many"

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion I'll use [useFormik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/useFormik) hook  I think this hook is easy to understand.

(The final code is place at the end)

**First:** declare initialValues to have array field like this AND it should have unique id because if you use index as key when map sometimes react will not render correctly. In this example I use [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {
    contacts: [
      {
        id: uuid(),
        name: "",
        email: "",
      },
    ],
  }
});
```

**Then:** I'll create 2 function for handle adding and handle removing

```
const handleAddField = () => {
  formik.setFieldValue("contacts", [
    ...formik.values.contacts,
    { id: uuid(), name: "", email: "" },
  ]);
};

const handleRemoveField = (id) => {
  formik.setFieldValue(
    "contacts",
    formik.values.contacts.filter((contact) => contact.id !== id)
  );
};
```

**Finally:** Just render it with map like this

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  {formik.values.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
    <div key={contact.id}>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contacts[${index}].name`)} />
      <label>Email</label>
      <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contacts[${index}].email`)} />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveField(contact.id)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  ))}
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" onClick={handleNewField}>
    Add Field
  </button>
</form>
```

---

The final code look like this - here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-dynamic-field-8gkxd)

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      contacts: [
        {
          id: uuid(),
          name: "",
          email: "",
        },
      ],
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });

  const handleNewField = () => {
    formik.setFieldValue("contacts", [
      ...formik.values.contacts,
      { id: uuid(), name: "", email: "" },
    ]);
  };

  const handleRemoveField = (id) => {
    formik.setFieldValue(
      "contacts",
      formik.values.contacts.filter((contact) => contact.id !== id)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        {formik.values.contacts.map((contact, index) => (
          <div key={contact.id}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contacts[${index}].name`)} />
            <label>Email</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contacts[${index}].email`)} />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveField(contact.id)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleNewField}>
          Add Field
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with easy?

These are the steps you need in order to create a dynamic form in Formik

1. Save the fields in a state variable

```
const [fields, setFields] = useState([{name: "facebook", value: "facebook.com"}])
```

2. Generate the `initialValues` for the form, something like

```
const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
    const tempInitialValues = {};
    fields.forEach(field => {
      if (!tempInitialValues[field.name]) {
        tempInitialValues[field.name] = field.value;
      }
    });
    setInitialValues(tempInitialValues);
  }, [fields]);
```

Add `fields` to the dependency array so it is re-generated every time you add or remove a field

3. Add your functions to add and remove fields

```
const addNewField = () => {
    setFields(fields => [
      ...fields,
      {
        name: "instagram",
        value: "instagram.com"
      }
    ]);
  };
```

4. Render your Form dynamically

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues}>
  {props => (
    <div>
      <form>{fields.map(field => {
        <Field/>
      }}</form>
    </div>
  )}
</Formik>
```